# Отображение рамки камеры 2D Unity

Tags: unity3d, камера

Когда камера не выделена, то рамки нет. Когда выделена - рамка есть. Гизмо включен. Создал просто новый проект, больше ничего не трогал

Второй день в юнити. Гугли - ответа не нашёл.

[image: Рамки нет]

[image: Рамка есть]

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил наложением скрипта на камеру (подсказал человек)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        float verticalHeightSeen = GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize * 2.0f;
        float verticalWidthSeen = verticalHeightSeen * GetComponent<Camera>().aspect;


        Gizmos.color = Color.gray;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(verticalWidthSeen,verticalHeightSeen,0));
    }
```

}

Может у кого-то есть метод попроще?

Answer (score 0):

Прошёл уже год и скорее всего автор решил проблему, но для тех, кто ещё не разобрался со всем этим: попробуйте растегать камеру (Untagged) а потом снова придать тег Main Camera.
Видно, что при редактировании другого объекта рамки камеры не видно
[image: Камера без тега]
[image: Видно, что при редактировании другого объекта рамки камеры не видно]
Дали тег камере - тогда всё будет выглядеть совсем иначе, теперь при редактировании куба рамки видны[image: Дали тег камере]
[image: Теперь при редактировании куба рамки видны]